# Css file not responding at django project

Tags: django

I am trying to change navbar color through css file at django. But cant. Here is the folders:

[folders of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytDb.png)

[base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQl34.png)

[home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAtiP.png)

[main.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0dvu.png)

Comment: type your code as text wrapped with ( ``` ``` ) without parentheses, don't post it as an image

Comment: Calm down man, the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the nav `background-color` to #FFFFFF which is pure white, are you sure it's not working? Try checking that the CSS file is actually loading.

What can often happen is that the static files don't get reloaded, you can either empty the cache in your browser when reloading the page or append a version to your css when it's loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static_files/style.css' %}?version=x">
```

**Edit:** MaterializeCSS sets component colours in the class name, e.g.

```
<div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">This is a card panel with a teal lighten-2 class</div>
```

https://materializecss.com/color.html

Comment: nav is red now... i am trying to make it white

Comment: Just realised you're using MaterializeCSS, you need to set the colour in the class: https://materializecss.com/color.html (alternatively you could set the `background-color` to `!important` but I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Yes, my fault that didnt say it. But what if i want to change it through css?

Comment: I want to set width, position etc. on nav, and dont think that i should to it in the class

Comment: Using classes is how Materialize works, some nav-specific examples are shown [here](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) - you can still use CSS to adjust it but might need to set `!important` so it overrides any Materialize defaults (this can get messy)

Comment: I just didnt get the '!important'. Is there any example of it?

Comment: The use is `nav { background-color: white !important; }` and overrides other styling (unless it's called elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

The `class = 'nav'` property does not appear anywhere in your templates.  Please check that out. After that, you can try a hard reload. On windows, it's CTRL+F5.